# shift numpy array by row

Tags: python, numpy, shift

Array:

```
arr = np.ones([4,4])

array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

I use `shift` from `scipy.ndimage.interpolation` as follows:

```
shift(arr,1, cval=np.nan)

array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,   1.,   1.,   1.]])
```

HOWEVER, I want:

```
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ 1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ 1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [ 1.,   1.,   1.,   1.]])
```

Basically, I want to SHIFT all columns data down the rows and boot the last row out of my data set. `Pandas` has the shift function that can do this but I'm not certain how it can be done in `Numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `shift` parameter (second parameter) of the `shift` function from `scipy.ndimage.interpolation` as follows:

```
shift(arr, (1, 0), cval=np.nan)
```

Here, `(1, 0)` means a shift of `1` in the first dimension, and `0` in the second dimension.

Comment: Might also want to explicitly set `mode='constant'`