# scipy.ndimage.interpolation shift of numpy array gives erroneous result - bug?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan, scipy.ndimage

This question is an extension of [shift numpy array by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616688/shift-numpy-array-by-row/58616747#58616747)

If I `shift` (from `scipy.ndimage.interpolation`) using a test 3 x 5 x 5 array like so everything works as expected:

```
arr = np.ones([3,5,5])

array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])

shift(arr,(1,0,0), cval=np.nan)

array([[[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]],

       [[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.]],

       [[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.]]])
```

HOWEVER, if I perform the same shift on my 3 x 5 x 5 data array I get all np.nan values:

```
array([[[ 0.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan],
        [        nan,  0.        ,         nan,         nan, -1.07346633],
        [        nan,         nan,  0.        ,         nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan,  0.        ,         nan],
        [        nan,  1.07346633,         nan,         nan,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan],
        [        nan,  0.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,  0.        , -1.44470265,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,  1.44470265,  0.        ,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.        ,         nan,  1.80965682,         nan,         nan],
        [        nan,  0.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan],
        [-1.80965682,         nan,  0.        ,         nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan,  0.        ,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,  0.        ]]])

shift(stats1_arr,(1,0,0), cval=np.nan)

array([[[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]],

       [[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]]])
```

Am I doing something wrong (mis-using shift?) or is this a bug? Seems like a bug in `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. [According to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.shift.html), it's using spline interpolation of order 3 (by default), and your sparse matrix just ends up full of `np.nan` values because you can't really interpolate it.

You can essentially turn the interpolation 'feature' off by using `order=0`:

```
shift(stats1_arr, (1, 0, 0), cval=np.nan, order=0)
```

Which results in:

```
array([[[     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan]],

       [[ 0.     ,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,  0.     ,      nan,      nan, -1.07347],
        [     nan,      nan,  0.     ,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,      nan,  0.     ,      nan],
        [     nan,  1.07347,      nan,      nan,  0.     ]],

       [[ 0.     ,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,  0.     ,      nan,      nan,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,  0.     , -1.4447 ,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,  1.4447 ,  0.     ,      nan],
        [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,  0.     ]]])
```

Comment: ahhhh - gotcha gotcha. Thank you very much. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @codingknob You're welcome. Other forms of appreciation also accepted :P